# Segmentation fault 11 trying to get data after using memcpy

Tags: c

I am running into a problem when I run my `a.out` file using the `./a.out` command. I am getting segmentation code error number 11. I am getting a segmentation fault when trying to access sharedMemory. I use `memcpy` to paste the data into shared memory. It is Segmentation fault 11.

Am I accessing the memory correctly?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<time.h>
int main(){
    pid_t childPid;
    childPid = fork();
    char *shm;
    if(childPid == 0){
        char *args[] ={"ls","-l",NULL};
        int shmid;
        int shsize = 100;
        key_t key;
        char *s;
        key = 9876;
        shmid = shmget(key,shsize, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
        if(shmid < 0){
            printf("error getting shmid");
            exit(1);
        }

        shm = shmat(shmid,NULL,0);
        if(shm == (char *) -1){
            printf("error getting shared memory");
            exit(1);
        }
        time_t startTime;
        gettimeofday(&startTime,0);
        memcpy(shm,&startTime,sizeof(startTime));
        time_t endTime;
        execvp(args[0],args);
        printf("successfuly created child proceess");
        exit(0);
    }

    else if (childPid <0){
        printf("unsuccessfuly created child proccess");



        else{
            int returnStatus;
            waitpid(childPid,&returnStatus,0);
            if(returnStatus == 0){
                printf("The child terminated normally");
                printf("%s",*shm);
            }

            if(returnStatus == 1){

                printf("The child terminated with error");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This code does not compile.  Please post your real code.

Comment: Also eliminate all warnings (compile with -Wall). Add `#include<sys/time.h>`, `#include <sys/wait.h>` and `#include<memory.h>`, this will get rid of some warnings and show some other warnings that will be more relevant to your problem.

Comment: you did not react on my answer nor the remark above, this was useless for you ? I just answer on your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55067862/protecting-shared-data-and-sharing-same-stack may be I loose again my time because you are not interrested too ?

Answer (score 3):

In

```
    time_t startTime;
    gettimeofday(&startTime,0);
```

the first argument of *gettimeofday* must be a `struct timeval *` not a `time_t *`

so

```
    struct timeval startTime;
    gettimeofday(&startTime,0);
```

---

In

```
char *shm;
...
printf("%s",*shm);
```

you must not dereference *shm* because currently the ascii code of its first character is used as the address of a string, must be

```
char *shm;
...
printf("%s",shm);
```

---

After

```
else if (childPid <0){
    printf("unsuccessfuly created child proccess");
```

a `}` is missing

---

I encourage you to compile asking the compiler to produce warnings, with *gcc* use the options `-pedantic -Wall`